# How to build gremlin query to add and drop vertex as part one transaction

Tags: python, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I want to build a gremlin_python query dynamically that adds vertices and deletes vertices in single transaction.

For Ex: Lets say my graph has a vertex with property desc ='toBeDeleted'. I want to build a query to add vertices with desc  = `desc_1`, `desc_2`, `desc_3` and delete vertex with desc = `toBeDeleted` can I do something like this?

```
g = Graph().traversal().withRemote(DriverRemoteConnection('neptune_end_point', 'g'))
temp = g
i = 1
while i < 4:
 temp = temp.addV('vertex_label').property('desc', 'desc_{}'.format(i))
 i = i+1
temp = temp.V().has('vertex_label', 'desc', 'toBeDeleted').drop()
temp.toList()
```

note: I have tried this but it creates desc_1, desc_2, desc_3 twice.

I am also looking a way to delete edges as well as part of one transaction

Comment: What do you mean by "creates desc_1, desc_2, desc_3 twice"? are you saying that you get 6 vertices added rather than 3?